# C++ greater than or equal to operator

Tags: c++, operators, overloading

In C++, for the operator greater than or equal to (">="), is it enough to have the operators equal ("=") and greater (">") overloaded to have functionality for the greater than or equal to (">=")? Or do I need to overload the operator (">=") to have functionality for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using an obvious notation, "`>` || `==`" is actually an over-requirement for `>=`.

Although note that for *all* the relational operators, you only actually need `<`, since equivalence is established if `a < b` and `b < a` are both false. In fact this is one of the concepts used in ordered C++ standard library containers.

Comment: I think it should be > || ==. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @VasiMarin: Oops. Let's publish jointly!

Comment: @user463035818: It means that you can derive ">=" from ">".

Comment: oh sure, maybe "although" should be "because"? I guess thats what caused my confusion, otherwise it completely makes sense

Answer (score 17):

`operator >=` is not a combination of `operator >` and `operator =`.  `operator >=` is its own operator but you can implement it in terms of `operator <`  Typically you would have something like

> ```
> inline bool operator==(const X& lhs, const X& rhs){ /* do actual comparison */ }
> inline bool operator!=(const X& lhs, const X& rhs){return !operator==(lhs,rhs);}
> inline bool operator< (const X& lhs, const X& rhs){ /* do actual comparison */ }
> inline bool operator> (const X& lhs, const X& rhs){return  operator< (rhs,lhs);}
> inline bool operator<=(const X& lhs, const X& rhs){return !operator> (lhs,rhs);}
> inline bool operator>=(const X& lhs, const X& rhs){return !operator< (lhs,rhs);}
> ```

From sbi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/4342498) on [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 13):

> is it enough to have the operators equal ("=")

Equal operator in c++ is `==`

> OR do I need to overload the operator (">=") to have functionality for it?

It depends what you mean by functionality. If you mean that if you define `operator==` and `operator>` will compiler generate `operator>=` automagically for you? No, it would not, you have to implement it using existing operators or not.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the compiler will automatically do that.

Comment: Now in C++20, will the compiler generate the >= automagically ?

Answer (score 13):

No, C++ does not write those operators for you.

If you think that sucks, you are right.  A bunch of ways to make this suck less have been done.  I'll talk about 4 of them.

## Wait for [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), if you write [`operator<=>`](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r0.pdf) (the [3-way](https://www.google.com/search?q=spaceship+operator+C%2B%2B&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab) "spaceship" operator) properly, or `=default` it, then all of `<`, `<=`, `>=`, `>`, `!=` and `==` will be written for you.

```
struct bob {
  int x,y;
  auto operator<=>( bob const& )const = default;
};
```

The above `bob` has every `<` `==` etc operator written for it by C++ now.

## Just write them

Prior to [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you have to write all of them if you want all of them.  This is tedious and error-prone.

Using `std::tie` and invoking `<` and the like on them is slightly less error-prone:

```
struct bob {
  int x, y;
  friend bool operator<( bob const& lhs, bob const& rhs ) {
    return std::tie(lhs.x, lhs.y) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y);
  }
};
```

or even

```
struct bob {
  int x, y;
  friend auto as_tie( bob const& b ) { // C++14
    return std::tie(b.x, b.y);
  }
  friend bool operator<( bob const& lhs, bob const& rhs ) {
    return as_tie(lhs) < as_tie(rhs);
  }
};
```

because `tuple` does a proper lexographic comparison; writing lexographic comparions without bugs is annoying.

## Metaprogram your way around it

When comparing strings you usually use `strcmp`.  This returns a negative number if less, a positive number if greater, and 0 if equal.  This pattern can be more efficient than doing `<` or `==` repeatedly.

Making a single `strcmp` like function produce `<` `==` and the other comparison operations can be done:

```
namespace utils {
  template<class D>
  struct use_cmp {
    friend bool operator<( use_cmp<D> const& lhs, use_cmp<D> const& rhs ) {
      return cmp( lhs.self(), rhs.self() ) < 0;
    }
    friend bool operator>( use_cmp<D> const& lhs, use_cmp<D> const& rhs ) {
      return cmp( lhs.self(), rhs.self() ) > 0;
    }
    friend bool operator<=( use_cmp<D> const& lhs, use_cmp<D> const& rhs ) {
      return cmp( lhs.self(), rhs.self() ) <= 0;
    }
    friend bool operator>=( use_cmp<D> const& lhs, use_cmp<D> const& rhs ) {
      return cmp( lhs.self(), rhs.self() ) >= 0;
    }
    friend bool operator==( use_cmp<D> const& lhs, use_cmp<D> const& rhs ) {
      return cmp( lhs.self(), rhs.self() ) == 0;
    }
    friend bool operator!=( use_cmp<D> const& lhs, use_cmp<D> const& rhs ) {
      return cmp( lhs.self(), rhs.self() ) != 0;
    }
  private:
    D const& self() const { return *static_cast<D const*>(this); }
  };
}
```

Now supose we have a type:

```
struct bob {
  int x, y;
};
```

and we want to be able to use comparison operators on it:

```
struct bob : utils::use_cmp<bob>
{
  int x, y;
  bob( int x_, int y_ ):x(x_), y(y_) {} // constructor
  friend int cmp( bob const& lhs, bob const& rhs ) {
    if (lhs.x < rhs.x) return -1;
    if (lhs.x > rhs.x) return 1;
    if (lhs.y < rhs.y) return -1;
    if (lhs.y > rhs.y) return 1;
    return 0;
  }
};
```

and using the magic of [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) `bob` now has every comparison operator written for it.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19ed257e3526f04f).

That annoying `friend int cmp` (which gets more annoying the more members you have in it) can be handled by yet more boilerplate helper code:

```
namespace utils {
  template<class...Ts>
  int cmp( std::tuple<Ts...> const& lhs, std::tuple<Ts...> const& rhs );
  template<class T, class...LowPriority>
  int cmp( T const& lhs, T const& rhs, LowPriority&&... );

  template<class...Ts, std::size_t...Is>
  int tuple_cmp( std::tuple<Ts...> const& lhs, std::tuple<Ts...> const& rhs, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
    int result = 0;
    ( (result = cmp( std::get<Is>(lhs), std::get<Is>(rhs) )) && ... );
    return result;
  }

  template<class...Ts>
  int cmp( std::tuple<Ts...> const& lhs, std::tuple<Ts...> const& rhs ) {
     return tuple_cmp( lhs, rhs, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{} );
  }
  template<class T, class...LowPriority>
  int cmp( T const& lhs, T const& rhs, LowPriority&&... ) {
    if (lhs < rhs) return -1;
    if (rhs < lhs) return 1;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

which is yet more arcane code, but you get a simpler `bob`:

```
struct bob : utils::use_cmp<bob>
{
  int x, y;
  bob( int x_, int y_ ):x(x_), y(y_) {}

  friend auto as_tie(bob const& b) {
    return std::tie(b.x,b.y);
  }
  friend int cmp( bob const& lhs, bob const& rhs ) {
    return utils::cmp( as_tie(lhs), as_tie(rhs) );
  }
};
```

Note, however, that all of this is done and better by `operator<=>` in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20).

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfb68c948f1654a8).

## Use someone else's solution

This is similar to the approach [boost::operators](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.operators) uses to write these operators for you.